# Example of $\omega$-limit set with two singular points (at least).

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

According to Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem, if an orbit in the plane contains only finitely many fixed points, then the $\omega$-limit set is either

- a fixed point,
- a periodic orbit, or
- a connected set composed of a finite number of fixed points together with orbits connecting them.

We can see examples of the first and the second cases with the vector field $F(x,y)=(-\sin(x),y)$.

**What are some examples of the third case?**

Comment: I don't know about simplest possible, but there's an example on p. 224 in Teschl's ODE book, [available from his web page](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/).

Comment: @HansLundmark It is simple enough for my purposes. I removed "simplest" from the question. Could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example is given on p. 224 in Gerald Teschl's book [Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Egerald/ftp/book-ode/):
$$
\dot x = y+x^2 - \tfrac14 x (y-1+2x^2)
,\qquad
\dot y = -2(1+y)x
.
$$
[image: Phase portrait]